# Does retraining the ML with the same dataset count an epoch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, artificial-intelligence, epoch

I developed the ML for my research, and it needs to be trained with a large amount of data, actually I have to train it for 100 epochs. But, my macbook (m2 13") can't hold it, and also I have to use my laptop for studying, so I can't leave it train all day. I WANNA KNOW. If I seperate the amount of epochs into 10 epochs and train the ML with the same dataset in 10 days, will it give the same result with training 100 epochs for one time?

I use "Yolov5".

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to answer if you gave us the libraries you're using for your project.

But you should search for training checkpoints these let you train for a certain number of epochs and then start from the last checkpoint and train another X epochs later.